# sp_getapplock without transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm implementing stored procedure that won't have transactions inside. Actually, it will, but only on specific spots to reduce time to minimum. Nature of stored procedure is so I only want one runinng at a time.

I tried to use sp_getapplock but quickly found that it needs to be inside transaction.

Is there any other alternative where I can place lock on whole procedure but without wrapping it into transaction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

pass in Session via @LockOwner to get a Session-scope lock; this does not need a transaction to be alive when lock is taken.

For example

```
EXEC @res = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
..
code
..

EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session';
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you post example?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Add `@LockOwner = 'Session'` to sp_releaseapplock also, otherwise it throws error

Comment: I believe you must provide the `@LockOwner` when releasing too? At least I did, otherwise I got error "The statement or function must be executed in the context of a user transaction.". i.e. use `EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session';`

Comment: Also note that ending session releases session locks. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823(SQL.90).aspx, "Locks associated with the session are released when the session is logged out.".