# sp_GetAppLock without transaction in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking

The code in irunvar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532055/sp-getapplock-without-transaction) no longer works in SQL Server 2019.  When I run this code (and only this code)

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
print 'omg' 
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID';
```

I get

> The statement or function must be executed in the context of a user transaction.

Any ideas how I get an applock without a transaction these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match the lock and release you must specify the same `@LockOwner` for both operations:

```
declare @Status as Int;
EXEC @Status = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
print @Status;
print 'omg';
EXEC @Status = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Lock ID', @LockOwner = 'Session';
print @Status;
```